# Looking for "day view" javascript library/plugin/calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, calendar

Our project seeks to render calendars similar to outlook's web view (i.e. where you can view a calendar in 'day', 'week', or 'month' view). To clarify: we do *not* need 'date picker' functionality (i.e. used by the out-of-the-box jquery UI calendar plugin).

At this point I've found jquery plugins to render a calendar in "month view" and "week view".

Can anyone recommend a 'day view' jquery plugin or javascript library? We can write our own plugin, but wanted to check with the hive-mind first.

Thanks in advance,

bill

Appendix A. Jquery plugins for Rendering Calendars

## ***Week views***

Jquery week calendar:
 http://www.redredred.com.au/projects/jquery-week-calendar/

## ***Month views***

Jmonth calendar

Full Calendar

Comment: Did you ever find a Day View calendar. I have a similar requirement myself and trying to avoid recreating the wheel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see [Eyecon](http://eyecon.ro/datepicker/) datepicker. The last example on this page has only the current date. Maybe this is what you need.

Answer (score 6):

I did a same search today and found an awesome control.

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/

Answer (score 0):

The [JQuery Event Calendar Plugin](http://www.web-delicious.com/jquery-events-calendar-wdcalendar/) as a day view mode.

Here is a [sample test version](http://www.web-delicious.com/jquery-plugins-demo/wdCalendar/sample.php).